# How to define a constructor function that makes objects with getters and setters?

Tags: javascript, object, definition, getter-setter, defineproperty

I'm working on creating an object definition to encapsulate several properties. I have 4 requirements for this object:

- more than one instance can be created at any time
- only properties defined on the object can be set/get
- the object must be stringify-able (just the properties and associated values)
- the stringified version must be parse-able and return the object

This is a simplified version of what I have so far:

```
function Car() {
    
    var _make;

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'make', {
        get: function() {
            return _make;
        },
        set: function(make) {
            _make = make;           
        }
    });
    Object.preventExtensions(this);
}
```

I'm unsure if this is the simplest approach for defining an object with getters and setters. Is there an alternative to using `Object.defineProperty`, or is this the new norm?

This approach also requires me to write my own `stringify` method (see below) since calling `JSON.stringify` will strip off functions, and this will strip off `make`. Is there an alternative to writing my own? Can I change my object definition somehow?

```
Car.prototype.stringify = function () {
    return JSON.stringify({ make: this.make});
}
```

Additionally, I must supply an optional constructor arg to be able to instantiate a `Car` from a JSON object:

```
function Car(car) {
    var _make;
    if(car !== undefined && car != null) {
        _make = car.make;
    }
    ...
}
```

Again, is this the best approach to meet all the requirements?

Comment: "`JSON.stringify` will strip off functions..." -- `make` is not a function. It is an *accessor property* that *has* functions. That said, it's not clear to me why you don't just use a normal data property for `make` and use `this.make` anywhere you currently use `_make`. (If you have functions inside your constructor that use a different `this`, you can capture the desired `this` with `var that = this` (or similar) and use `that.make`.)

Comment: You might want to look at [Records](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/3.3.0/type-definitions/Immutable.d.ts#L1578-L1637) of [Immutable](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

Comment: @apsillers Not quite sure exactly what you're proposing. Do you mind changing the following fiddle with your proposal: http://jsfiddle.net/xx1qp1e8/1/

Comment: @user1491636 Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/xx1qp1e8/2/ I've made `this.make` a simple data property and eliminated `_make` entirely. Also, I've simplified your `stringify` method. (Note that with `defineProperty`, you must explicitly use `enumerable: true` to make the property enumerable and included in `JSON.stringify` output.) If you have a reason why my proposal won't work for your actual needs, clarify it in your question.

Comment: @apsillers Ah ok, makes more sense... much simpler. Also, the Car stringify method is really not needed anymore I guess. Thanks!

Comment: @apsillers Follow-up question... Is there an alternative to defining object variables with `this.var=undefined`? If I had a list of 20 vars, setting each to undefined seems a little odd. Is this the only way I can fulfill my requirements?

Comment: @user1491636 You can loop over a list of property names as strings and use bracket notation: `this[propName] = undefined;` So a full example might be `var pList = ['a','b']; for(var i=0;i<pList.length;p++) { var pName=pList[i]; this[pName] = undefined; }`

Answer (score 4):

To show up `make` property while using `JSON.stringify`, you have to set the `enumerable` to **True** (By default, **False**).

> > **configurable**: `true` if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.
> >     Defaults to `false`.
> >
> > **enumerable**: `true` if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object.
> >     Defaults to `false`.
> >     function Car() {

```
var _make;

Object.defineProperty(this, 'make', {
    get: function() {
        return _make;
    },
    set: function(make) {
        _make = make;           
    },
    enumerable:true 
});
Object.preventExtensions(this);
```

}